# How to pass a function with more than one argument to pandas converters?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, lambda

I have a CSV file that I need to read as a DataFrame, but some transformations in the columns are required.

This is what's in my file (the arrays come as strings):

```py
   array1     array2       matrix1                      matrix2  size1  size2
(1, 2, 3)  (4, 5, 6)  (1, 2, 3, 4)  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)      2      3
(3, 2, 1)  (6, 5, 4)  (4, 3, 2, 1)  (9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)      2      3
```

The array columns need to be converted to arrays, and the matrix columns need to be converted to matrices according to the given size. (The actual process is more complex and the values in the data actually correspond to the lower triangle of each matrix.)

So, the expected output DataFrame is:

```py
      array1     array2                   matrix1                                            matrix2  size1  size2
0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]  [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]  [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, ...      2      3

1  [3, 2, 1]  [6, 5, 4]  [[4.0, 3.0], [2.0, 1.0]]  [[9.0, 8.0, 7.0], [6.0, 5.0, 4.0], [3.0, 2.0, ...      2      3
```

I'm using `converters` to convert the array columns as I read them. So, if I only convert the arrays:

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

csv_file = 'data.csv'
array_columns = ['array1', 'array2']
array_converters = dict([(column, lambda x: np.fromstring(x[1:-1], sep=',').astype('int')) \
                          for column in array_columns])
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, converters=array_converters)
```

results in:

```
            array1           array2       matrix1                      matrix2  size1  size2
0  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]  [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]  (1, 2, 3, 4)  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)      2      3

1  [3.0, 2.0, 1.0]  [6.0, 5.0, 4.0]  (4, 3, 2, 1)  (9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)      2      3
```

And I can then parse the matrix columns by doing this:

```py
matrix_columns = [(f'matrix{i}', f'size{i}') for i in range(1, 3)]
for array_str_column, size_column in matrix_columns:
    df[array_str_column] = df.apply(lambda x: array_to_matrix(x[array_str_column], \
                                    x[size_column]), axis=1)
```

where `array_to_matrix` is a function that takes the array string and transforms it into a matrix:

```py
def array_to_matrix(array_str, size):
    array = np.fromstring(array_str[1:-1], sep=',')
    return array.reshape(size, size)
```

However, I haven't been able to find a way to parse the matrices using converters.

I've tried rewriting the for loop like this:

```py
matrix_converters = dict([(array_str_column, df.apply(lambda x: array_to_matrix(x[array_str_column], \
                x[size_column]), axis=1)) for array_str_column, size_column in matrix_columns])
```

But, of course, `df` will not be defined before calling `pd.read_csv`, and I want all the converters (for array and matrices) to be applied then (I can merge `array_converters` and `matrix_converters` into a single dictionary).

I've tried passing the arguments in different ways. For example:

```py
matrix_columns = [(f'matrix{i}', f'size{i}') for i in range(1, 3)]
matrix_converters = dict([(array_str_column, lambda x: array_to_matrix(x, size_column)) \
                           for array_str_column, size_column in matrix_columns])
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, converters=matrix_converters)
```

The issue is that the `x` in the `lambda` corresponds only to the string `"(1,2,3,4)"` in the case of the first row, and not to the entire row, and therefore, it doesn't contain the data of any other column. How can I pass the sizes to the function `array_to_matrix`?

I've also tried adding another argument to the `lambda` using `x, y` but I get the error `TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "array1": ["(1, 2, 3)", "(3, 2, 1)"],
        "array2": ["(4, 5, 6)", "(6, 4, 5)"],
        "matrix1": ["(1, 2, 3, 4)", "(4, 3, 2, 1)"],
        "matrix2": ["(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)", "(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)"],
        "size1": [2, 2],
        "size2": [3, 3],
    }
)
```

I suggest a different approach:

```py
# Transform strings into lists
for col in ["array1", "array2", "matrix1", "matrix2"]:
    df[col] = (
        df[col]
        .apply(lambda x: x.strip("(").strip(")").split(", "))
        .apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x])
    )

# Convert lists into lists of lists
for matrix, size in zip(
    [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("matrix")],
    [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("size")],
):
    df[matrix] = df.apply(
        lambda x: [
            x[matrix][i : i + x[size]] for i in range(0, len(x[matrix]), x[size])
        ],
        axis=1,
    )
```

So that:

```py
      array1     array2           matrix1                            matrix2  size1  size2
0  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6]  [[1, 2], [3, 4]]  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]      2      3
1  [3, 2, 1]  [6, 4, 5]  [[4, 3], [2, 1]]  [[9, 8, 7], [6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]]      2      3
```